# How to remove some drivers when config kernel?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, beagleboneblack, buildroot

I using beaglebone black board. I want to customize linux's kernel to optimize boot time. I want to remove the graphics driver. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: what search terms did you try?

Comment: most of the boot time will be spent initializing user space. There are nice ways to create 'bootchart' output. Also it can be worth it to crank up the serial console baud rate to e.g. 1MBaud if your interface supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have linux kernel for beagleboard, you just can use command

```
make menuconfig
```

from the kernel directory. Then you can configure your kernel. You can go to Device Drivers -> Graphic Support and turn off some unnecessary options. And after that you can compile your kernel

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE='your compile'
```

and get uImage or zImage file.

If you need more complicated information, use this [buildroot lab](http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-labs.pdf). There is a step by step creating of beaglebone kernel. It was very helpful for me.

Comment: thanks Victor V !! Your advises are very useful for me to over come this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[*same answer as given by Victor V., but assuming you build the kernel with buildroot*]

Assuming you built your system using buildroot (since this question has the buildroot tag):

- Run `make linux-menuconfig`.
- Go to Device Drivers -> Graphic Support and turn off unnecessary options.
- Run `make` and deploy to your beaglebone.
- If you're satisfied, run `make linux-update-defconfig` to save the configuration.

See [the Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-store-package-config) for information about the Linux configuration in Buildroot.